# Free an PTP USB device from GVFS usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, gnome, iphone

I have an iphone SE connected via USB as a [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol) device. Under gphoto2: protocol.

My goal is to connect it to a KVM virtual machine via SPICE.

The problem is even when i unmount the device in caja (ubuntu-mate default file manager), it is still used/open by some process and cannot use it in another process.

It is not an USB mass storage device, **and has not a block device**.
So it is not found under `mount` , `lsof` .
I think it is used by some `GVFS` process.

**Is there any way to free the device from `GVFS`?**

Some user solved it by uninstalling a package, but i cannot use the solution because my desktop package `ubuntu-mate-desktop` depends on it.
[KVM: iphone passthrough to windows guest](https://superuser.com/questions/947582/kvm-iphone-passthrough-to-windows-guest)

*gvfs-mount --list -i:*

> Volume(0): iPhone   Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorGPhoto2)
>   ids:    unix-device: '/dev/bus/usb/003/030'
>   activation_root=gphoto2://[usb:003,030]/   themed icons: 
>   [camera-photo]   symbolic themed icons:  [camera-photo-symbolic] 
>   [camera-symbolic]  [camera-photo]  [camera]
>   can_mount=1
>   can_eject=0
>   should_automount=1

*gvfs-mount -e gphoto2://[usb:003,030]*

> Error ejecting mount: mount doesn't implement "eject" or
>   "eject_with_operation"

***spice-client-error-quark: Could not redirect Apple Inc. iPhone [05ac:12a8] at 3-32: Device is in use by another application (0***)

Enviroment:

Ubuntu-MATE 16.04.2 LTS

Linux version 4.4.0-65-generic (buildd@lgw01-12) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 23 17:49:58 UTC 2017

*gvfs-info -f gphoto2://[usb:003,030]/*

> attributes:   filesystem::size: 16000000000   filesystem::free:
>   9223761920   filesystem::type: gphoto2   filesystem::readonly: FALSE
>   filesystem::use-preview: 1   gvfs::backend: gphoto2

Comment: Stupid question (I don't run a Gnome desktop): What happens if you kill `gvfsd`?

Comment: No change. There are many gvfsd subprocesses. I tried killing gvfsd-gphoto2, no change. I even killed usbmuxd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried killing `usbmuxd` again and strangely it worked. 
Maybe it is because i did the following before :

```
chmod a-x /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-gphoto2
chmod a-x /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
```